# help with isomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let H = {u, v,w, x, y, z} be a group (with multiplication *) and  $\theta$ : $S_3$ - H be
an isomorphism with $\theta$(e) = u, $\theta$(1, 2) = x, $\theta$(1, 3) = y, $\theta$(2, 3) = z,$\theta$(1, 2, 3) = v ,$\theta$(1, 3, 2) = w. 
Find x * w, $w^{−1}$, $v^5$, z * v$^{−1}$ * x.

I know for x * w, I have to calculate it by (1,2)(1,3,2).

However I'm not sure how to go any further than this.

Answer (score 0):

For x*w, as you said, calculate $(1,2)(1,3,2)=(1,3)$ and then apply $\theta$ on it to get $\theta{(1,3)}=y$ , now $w^{-1}=(1,3,2)^{-1}=(2,3,1)$. Now you can do rest two yourself.

Comment: what steps did you take to calculate (1,2)(1,3,2) = (1,3)

Comment: I have the answers to each part, I just want to understand the steps taken to get the answers

Comment: Ohh you should know how to compose two cycles, it is the first step. anyways let me tell you how it is done. $(1,3,2)$ means $1$ goes to $3$ , $3$ goes to $2$ and $2$ goes to $1$. ok. so on the right most cycle you see the image of $1$ , it is $3$ , now $3$ goes to $3$ in the cycle on left of the cycle we just dealt with so in the final cycle you know that $1$ goes to $3$ now check in similar fashion where $3$ goes to, it will end up on $1$, so just close the cycle there as soon as it starts repeating. also $2$ goes to $2$, so you do not write $(2)$ as a cycle in the answer as it is obvious